# Force doxygen modules to begin with lower case letter

Tags: c, doxygen

I'm documenting a C project using doxygen, and am grouping collection of files into modules (where each module contains all documentation for a c style class). Everything I have works fine, except that all Module names begin with a capital letter, even when I create the module group with an all lower case name.

For example, the following doxygen comments will generate a module "Foobar" in my documentation, even though I add to group "foobar" and want the module to be called "foobar":

```
    /**
     *@addtogroup foobar
     *@{
     * (some documentation elements...)
     *@}
     */
```

While the capitalization does not affect the documentation in any serious way I would like to fix it for consistency (and because I can't make myself let it go). Google has come up dry, any suggestions?

Comment: Hm. I can't find a solution either. Are you sure you're not referencing Foobar somewhere else that's causing that capitalization to stick during some kinda "preprocessing"? And, it's a longshot, but the only reference I see to capitalization is the section on "CASE_SENSE_NAMES" at http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/doc/doxygen.conf, but that shouldn't have anything to do with doxygen modifying _your_ capitalization. Good luck solving this!

Comment: I'm sure, I switched my "addtogroup" statements to "defgroup" to make sure that was only using each group name once. I guess I'll google a bit more, and if nothing comes up submit a bug report.

Answer (score 3):

I nearly missed this in the [doxygen manual](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html):

> To define a group, you should put the \defgroup command in a special comment block. The first argument of the command is a label that should uniquely identify the group. The second argument is the name or title of the group as it should appear in the documentation.

So you should be able to do

```
@addtogroup foobar foobar
```

Answer (score 1):

The [answer by @E-rich](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18220125/434551) provides a working solution.

However, if you use

```
\addtogroup foobar
```

in lots of places/files, it will be a maintenance headache to have to use

```
\addtogroup foobar foobar
```

in all those places. It will be better to use:

```
\defgroup foobar foobar
```

and then leave the use of

```
\addtogroup foobar
```

as is.

Using my suggestion, it will be easy to change the name to something more descriptive if you ever feel like it.

```
\defgroup foobar The Foo and Bar Module
```